# how can i order this associate array php?

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm student, i have this array:

```
 {
        "user": "DAV",
        "checks": [
            {
                "result": "OKEY",
                "idCheck": 13,
            },
            {                             
                "result": "1",
                "idCheck": 14,                  
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "user": "DAV",            
        "checks": [
            {
                "result": "X",
                "idCheck": 14,
            },
            {
                "idCheck": 13,
                "result": null
            }
        ]
    }
```

Okey, thats my array, i want to order the "check" by the idCheck, because the second check, first id is 14 and the the seconds is 13. I dont know what i have to do. Maybe usort or something. I don't know

The result i want is this:

```
{
        "user": "DAV",
        "checks": [
            {
                "result": "OKEY",
                "idCheck": 13,
            },
            {                             
                "result": "1",
                "idCheck": 14,                  
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "user": "DAV",            
        "checks": [
            {
                "result": null,
                "idCheck": 13,
            },
            {
                "idCheck": 14,
                "result": X
            }
        ]
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, usort. If you don’t know how to use it, please go read up on it a bit first of all. And then you loop over your main array, and apply it for each `checks` entry at a time.

Comment: I found a nice place to play with all type of arrays here : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-date-element-in-php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
 foreach ($resultado as $key => $registro) {

            $registros = json_decode($registro['checks'],true);

            usort($registros, function($a, $b) {

                return $a['idCheck'] <=> $b['idCheck'];

            });

            $resultado[$key]['checks'] = $registros;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function:

```
arsort(array, sorttype)


arsort($users,SORT_NUMERIC);
```